# PHP stop user logging in from multiple browsers / PC's

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a column in my users table for 'online' which updates every 90 minutes with the last time they were online and it displays it like:

2012-11-22 19:15:18

How would I go about stopping people logging in if that user has been online within the last 90 minutes?

People are currently abusing my system by gaining x10 the legitimate amount of site currency.

EDIT:

HTML login form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
            <input class="l_form" onfocus="if(this.value == '<?=$lang['b_14']?>') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value = this.defaultValue }" value="<?=$lang['b_14']?>" name="login" type="text">
            <input class="l_form" onfocus="if(this.value == '<?=$lang['b_15']?>') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value = this.defaultValue }" value="<?=$lang['b_15']?>" name="pass" type="password">                                  
            <?=$errMsg?>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input class="gbut" name="connect" value="<?=$lang['b_13']?>" type="submit"><br /><br />
                <span style="float:right;display:inline"><a href="recover.php" style="font-size:12px"><?=$lang['b_16']?></a></span>
            </div>                                        
        </form>
```

There is a function for Is online:

```
/* User Session */
$is_online = (isset($_SESSION['EX_login']) ? true : false);
if(isset($_SESSION['EX_login'])){
$sql                = $db->Query("SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`online`) AS `online` FROM `users`     WHERE (`login`='".$_SESSION['EX_login']."' OR `email`='".$_SESSION['EX_login']."')");
$data               = $db->FetchArray($sql);
if($data['id'] == ''){
    session_destroy();
}elseif($data['online']+90 < time()){
    $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `online`=NOW() WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'");
}
}
```

Comment: We would need to see the function in which the user logs in, the one allowing the connection. This is the place where you can prevent the user from logging in twice or more.

Comment: I've added some code to the original post, I hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Can this not be done with MYSQL when the user tries to login something like SELECT * FROM users
WHERE lastlogintime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 90 MINUTE;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$currentTime = time();
$limit = $currentTime - 60 * 90;
if ($data['online'] < $limit) {
    echo "You have to wait..";
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Would that stop them from being able to log in?

Comment: I've never worked with Registration / user authentication etc would you be able to help me further if I message you?

Comment: i got your mail..but i tried inviting you to a chat room here..did you got the invitation..??

Comment: Never used that before, how do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Can this not be done with MYSQL when the user tries to login something like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE online <= NOW() - INTERVAL 90 MINUTE;
```

Comment: That's just a select, how would I then stop them from logging in?